# Sublime Text4でのCondaパッケージ使用時のエラー（No such file or directory: 'python')

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext

Sublime Text4で、anacondaを使用できるように環境を整えています。package installで「Conda」を「Build System」から選択できるようになったのは良かったのですが、どのようなコマンドでも、実行すると

"No such file or directory: 'python'"

が返ってきてしまいます。新しくbuild systemをつくり、anacondaのpython3のpathを通すと、python3が通常通り使えます。どうしても「Conda」にこだわる必要はないのですが、何らかの方法でanacondaのパッケージをSublime Text上でも使いたいと思っています。

[image: これはprint()を実行した時の結果です。]

Comment: `cmd:`のところに`python`と書いてあるのを`python3`にしてみるとかでは？ [Anaconda gives an error in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71067229/9014308) あるいはこんな設定ファイルを探して情報を更新するとか？ [sublime-text-conda/Conda (OSX).sublime-settings](https://github.com/mandeep/sublime-text-conda/blob/master/Conda%20(OSX).sublime-settings), [mandeep/sublime-text-conda](https://github.com/mandeep/sublime-text-conda/tree/master)

Comment: ありがとうございます！python3に書き換えて直りました！

Comment: 解決したなら自己回答してみてください。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) 私自身はMacもsublime textも使ったことが無く記事を紹介しただけですので。

Comment: 本サイトを使うのがはじめてのことで、申し訳ありません。回答いたしました。もし、また誤りなどございましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸甚です。

Answer (score 1):

本件、解決いたしました。

アドバイスいただいたcmdのpython（Conda.sublime-buildファイル内です）をpython3にすると、
"no such file or directory"のエラーはなくなり、通常通り、anacondaを使えます。

また、Conda.sublime-buildはsettingからアクセスできないので、パッケージビュアーから
探して直接書き込みます。なお、kunifさんからのアドバイスの他のコメントについても、
sublime condaを使う際にはとても役立ちますので、ご参照ください。